# Convert values at level {3} in a list to percentages

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list

```
m = {{x == 0, y == 0.29264681456942615}, {x == 30 , y == 0.2419119568894183},
     {x == 50 , y == 0.1485164898707659}, {x == 70 , y == 0.05437093382683481},
     {x == 90 , y == 1.`}}
```

and I want to change the unit into percent only for `y` value.
So the output that I want will be

```
m = {{x == 0, y == 29.264681456942615%}, {x == 30 , y == 24.19119568894183%},
     {x == 50 , y == 14.85164898707659%}, {x == 70 , y == 5.437093382683481},
     {x == 90 , y == 100%}}
```

How can I do this??

Comment: So in the new list the entries `y==` will contain strings (not numbers) ?

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: If you don't need the "%" symbol you can just do : `m /. {y == x_ -> y == 100 x}`.

Comment: If you need the "%" symbol you can do `m /. {y == x_ -> y == ToString[100 x]<>"%"}`

Comment: @b.gatessucks Sorry I did not test it just commented. This will work `m /. {y == x_ -> 
    y == Hold[ToString[Evaluate[100 x]] <> " %"]} // Release`

Comment: Is there any way that using At[...]?????

Comment: `m /. (y == n_) -> (y == PercentForm[n])`

Answer (score 9):

`StringForm[]` works nicely for this:

```
m /. y == n_?NumericQ :> y == StringForm["`1`%", InputForm[100 n]]
   {{x == 0, y == 29.264681456942615%}, {x == 30, y == 24.19119568894183%},
    {x == 50, y == 14.85164898707659%}, {x == 70, y == 5.437093382683481%},
    {x == 90, y == 100.%}}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 m /. y == y1_ :> y == ToString[100 y1] <> "%"
```

or

```
m /. y == x_ :> y == Row[{100 x, "%"}]
```

or

```
m /. y == x_ :>  y == AccountingForm[100 x, 6, NumberPadding -> {"", "%"}]
```

all give

```
{{x == 0, y == "29.2647%"}, {x == 30, y == "24.1912%"}, 
  {x == 50,y == "14.8516%"}, {x == 70, y == "5.43709%"}, {x == 90,  y == "100.%"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.0 we have `PercentForm`:

```
m =
  {{x == 0, y == 0.29264681456942615},
   {x == 30, y == 0.2419119568894183},
   {x == 50, y == 0.1485164898707659},
   {x == 70, y == 0.05437093382683481},
   {x == 90, y == 1.`}};


MapAt[PercentForm, m, {All, 2, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Specify one decimal place:

```
MapAt[PercentForm[#, {5, 1}] &, m, {All, 2, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]